# How do you reference another one of your classes in java?

Tags: java

in Class1 I have a private float float1

I have two public methods to access this variable.

```
public float getFloat1(){
        return float1;
    }

public void setFloat1(float f){
                float1 = f;
        }
```

How do I use these methods in Class2?

Comment: meant to be float1 = f;  Inside the second method my bad.

Comment: Can I suggest that you take the time to read Oracle's Java Tutorial, or one of the many Java textbooks out there.  This is a really basic question ... and if you need to ask it, you are probably going about learning Java the wrong way.

Comment: You can't directly access them, you need an object of `Class1`

Answer (score 3):

getFloat1() and setFloat1() are instance methods.If you want access any instance method then you should create an instance from the class.

```
Class1 c=new Class1();
float f=1.2F;
c.setFloat1(f);
System.out.println(c.getFloat1());
```

It seems that you are new to java.There are many java tutorials and books("Thinking in java" is a good one).

Comment: @StephenC Thinking in java is an amazing book

Answer (score 1):

```
 Class1 x = new Class1(); 
 x.setFloat1(1.0);
 float f = x.getFloat1();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must instantiate class 1 as such:

```
 Class1 c1 = new Class1();
 c1.setFloat(234.3);
 c1.getFloat();
```

This will be done in Class2.

Answer (score 0):

To access these methods specifically, you would have to create a new instance of `Class1` to use in `Class2`.

Example (assuming inside `Class2`):

```
Class1 cls = new Class1();
cls.setFloat(3.7);
cls.getFloat();  // Would get 3.7 back
```

Answer (score 0):

In Class2

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1();
class1.getFloat();
```

Answer (score 0):

What the other answers don't mention is that you can create static methods which can be accessed from outside the class without instantiating it. For example:

```
static public float getFloat()
{
   return float1;
}
```

from outside your class, you can access it as:

f = Class1.getFloat(); // no need to instantiate the class to access static methods